# VPS SSD hosting or normal RAID 10?

Tags: windows, vps, web-hosting, cache, windows-server-2012-r2

I have built a REST based API (using asp.net WebAPI) which returns RSS feeds to my mobile application. There are around 30,000 active users of my mobile application which access this RSS feed. As per Google analytics, there are around 500 users using the REST API any point of time. I expect this number to grow over the period of time.

To improve the performance of the API, i cache the RSS feed in memory so that subsequent requests are  served from memory only. The cache is refreshed every 3 hours.

**Question:** Given that most of the action is happening in memory, do i need to get a VPS hosting with SSD or a normal HDD (RAID 10) will suffice ?

**EDIT: Using Windows Server 2012 R2 softsyshosting**

Answer (score 3):

Test it and try it out with your *specific* application.

There may be other advantages to SSDs in your use-case (lower I/O latency, logging, etc.). But in the end, this is still a VPS, so there are other inefficiencies and questionable consolidation ratios. A crappy VPS on SSD is likely worse than a good VPS on standard hard disks. So if you haven't selected a provider yet, I think it makes sense to go with the most reputable provider and work from there.

Comment: Just to add, test SSD on a Decent Provider (AWS, Linode, DigitalOcean etc.)